# Is there a way to set the controller action for resources defined with only: or except:?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have some nested nested resources:

```
resources :assessments do
    member do
        get 'result'
    end
    resources :respondents, only: [:new, :create] do
      collection do
        post "invite", to: :invite_all
        get "invite", to: :new_invite
      end
    end
  end
```

For the line `resources :respondents, only: [:new, :create]` is it possible to set the action for the new and crate actions? You can use `to:` to set the action for a single resource. I'd like to avoid writing match statements if I can and keep things resourceful.

What motivates me to ask this is I'd like to be able to specify the action for a nested resource rather than have it route to the child resource's action. For example:

If I define

```
resources :assessments do
    resources :respondents
end
```

the path `/assessments/:id/respondents/new` will route to `respondents#new`. The problem with this it forces me to add logic to the new action to determine if the route contains the assessment id or not and then render the correct view. I'd like to be able to send the nested resource to a different action. Is there a "rails way" to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you simply not putting `resources :respondents` in `resources :assessments`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. The double negative is throwing me off. Could you give a snippet to illustrate your point? If it's just that simple, that would be wonderful!

Comment: Added an answer for readability.

Comment: I think ideally you want 1 route per resource, and you mentioning that sometimes the assessment id is *not present* suggests that this is not the case.  If the different view/logic required for each case you mention is minimal, e.g. some extra fields in the form, then I think testing for the presence of the assessment ID and reacting accordingly is acceptable.  If the difference in the *two new actions for the same resource* are substantial, then I think your problem might be a conceptual one and perhaps you need two different resources.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just not nest the resources like this:

```
resources :assessments do
  member do
    get 'result'
  end
end

resources :respondents, only: [:new, :create] do
  collection do
    post "invite", to: :invite_all
    get "invite", to: :new_invite
  end
end
```

Or to keep nesting for other actions (e.g. index) just define the new and create actions separately.

```
resources :assessments do
  member do
    get 'result'
  end
  resources :respondents
end

resources :respondents, only: [:new], path_names: { new: 'make' } do
  collection do
    post :generate
    post "invite", to: :invite_all
    get "invite", to: :new_invite
  end
end
```

This will create these routes:

```
         result_assessment GET    /assessments/:id/result(.:format)                          assessments#result
    assessment_respondents GET    /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents(.:format)          respondents#index
                           POST   /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents(.:format)          respondents#create
 new_assessment_respondent GET    /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents/new(.:format)      respondents#new
edit_assessment_respondent GET    /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents/:id/edit(.:format) respondents#edit
     assessment_respondent GET    /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents/:id(.:format)      respondents#show
                           PATCH  /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents/:id(.:format)      respondents#update
                           PUT    /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents/:id(.:format)      respondents#update
                           DELETE /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents/:id(.:format)      respondents#destroy
               assessments GET    /assessments(.:format)                                     assessments#index
                           POST   /assessments(.:format)                                     assessments#create
            new_assessment GET    /assessments/new(.:format)                                 assessments#new
           edit_assessment GET    /assessments/:id/edit(.:format)                            assessments#edit
                assessment GET    /assessments/:id(.:format)                                 assessments#show
                           PATCH  /assessments/:id(.:format)                                 assessments#update
                           PUT    /assessments/:id(.:format)                                 assessments#update
                           DELETE /assessments/:id(.:format)                                 assessments#destroy
      generate_respondents POST   /respondents/generate(.:format)                            respondents#generate
        invite_respondents POST   /respondents/invite(.:format)                              respondents#invite_all
                           GET    /respondents/invite(.:format)                              respondents#new_invite
            new_respondent GET    /respondents/make(.:format)                                respondents#new
```

This way you get new and create outside of of nested assessments.

I created these routes real quick locally and this is what was generated when running `rake routes`.

Comment: I don't think those resources are actually nested... I'd like the resources to be nested, so I can handle routes to the respondent resource, say for path (`/respondents`) and the nested resource (`/assessment/1/respondents/`) separately. 

The problem is, for a given HTTP verb, rails routes these to the same action. In this case `respondents#index`. I'd like them to be routed to different actions and to do it while using the only syntax to restrict the actions I want to support.

Comment: I made some changes, but I am missing something, give me one sec to fix it.

Comment: Alright, does that accomplish what you are trying to do?

Comment: No. POST `/respondents` and POST `/assessments/:assessment_id/respondents` both route to the same controller action. I would like to route them to different actions. Because they are different contexts, if you will.

Comment: Well, shoot. I guess you can't name the create action that way :/

I made some changes to include all your routes and simply made a custom `post :generate` route to satisfy the need for a custom create.

Comment: Ya and if I want a custom action for ` /assessments/:assessment_id/respondents/new`, more gymnastics are needed. `resources` is supposed to be a shortcut, but it looks like I need to buck up define the routes individually. :|

Comment: Yeah, that might be the best option :(